# Data time conversion with milleseconds

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 4 columns (start, starts.ms, end and end.ms), and my aim is to calculate the duration of each observation using this different variables.

```
start <- c("25/11/14 16:59:46", "25/11/14 16:59:29  ", "25/11/14 16:58:04")
start.ms <- c(976, 456, 30)
end <- c("25/11/14 17:00:00", "25/11/14 17:00:00", "25/11/14 17:00:00")
end.ms <- c(50, 111, 150)

df <-data.frame(start, start.ms, end, end.ms)

df$start.b <- with(df, paste(start, start.ms, sep = "."))
df$end.b <- with(df, paste(end, end.ms, sep = "."))
```

And after this, I want to convert the two last columns as data variable and differenciate them to get the duration !
When I use as.Date or strptime, R returns me NA value or nothing ...
Thank you in advance.

EDIT : for people who use the "strptime" funtion don't forget to add "options(digits.secs=3)" if you have milleseconds, the output will be in POSIXlt format.

Comment: Have you tried `op <- options(digits.secs=3);
strptime(df$start.b, format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS')`

Comment: I see , I forget the digits.secs option. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the comment as an answer.

```
  op <- options(digits.secs=3)
  strptime(df$start.b, format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS')
  #[1] "2014-11-25 16:59:46.976 EST" "2014-11-25 16:59:29.000 EST"
  #[3] "2014-11-25 16:58:04.300 EST"
```

Comment: Sorry but I discovered one problem, for example, in my vector end.ms, 50 ms is automaticly converting to 500 ms ! how to avoid this ?

Comment: @MostafaRifi Could you update the post with the relevant info or better would be to post as a new question as more people will look into it.

Comment: I solved it, I used an ifelse loop with the function paste. It works well ! sorry for the disruption !